# Преобразование JSON в новый

Tags: javascript, json, zabbix

Есть JSON:

```
{
"data":[
  {
     "{#ACLNAME}":"access-list inside line 1 extended permit icmp any any"
  },
  {
     "{#HINTS}":"0"
  },
  {
     "{#ACLNAME}":"access-list inside line 1 extended permit ip object-group ALL any"
  },
  {
     "{#HINTS}":"580848704"
  },
  {
     "{#ACLNAME}":"access-list inside line 1 extended permit ip host 10.3.2.1 any"
  },
  {
     "{#HINTS}":"0"
  },
  {
     "{#ACLNAME}":"access-list inside line 1 extended permit ip host 10.2.23.2 any"
  },
  {
     "{#HINTS}":"267629"
  }
]
}
```

Количество {#ACLNAME} и {#HINTS} всегда разное, но они парные, то есть четное количество.

Его нужно переделать в такой вид:

```
{
"data":[
  {
     "{#ACLNAME}":"access-list inside line 1 extended permit icmp any any",
     "{#HINTS}":"0"
  },
  {
     "{#ACLNAME}":"access-list inside line 1 extended permit ip object-group ALL any",
     "{#HINTS}":"580848704"
  },
  {
     "{#ACLNAME}":"access-list inside line 1 extended permit ip host 10.3.2.1 any",
     "{#HINTS}":"0"
  },
  {
     "{#ACLNAME}":"access-list inside line 1 extended permit ip host 10.2.23.2 any",
     "{#HINTS}":"267629"
  }
]
}
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя самый простой цикл, можно реализовать данную задачу

```js
const json = {
  data: [
    {
      "{#ACLNAME}": "access-list inside line 1 extended permit icmp any any"
    },
    {
      "{#HINTS}": "0"
    },
    {
      "{#ACLNAME}":
        "access-list inside line 1 extended permit ip object-group ALL any"
    },
    {
      "{#HINTS}": "580848704"
    },
    {
      "{#ACLNAME}":
        "access-list inside line 1 extended permit ip host 10.3.2.1 any"
    },
    {
      "{#HINTS}": "0"
    },
    {
      "{#ACLNAME}":
        "access-list inside line 1 extended permit ip host 10.2.23.2 any"
    },
    {
      "{#HINTS}": "267629"
    }
  ]
};

const result = { data: [] };

for (let i = 0; i < json.data.length; i += 2) {
  result.data.push({ ...json.data[i], ...json.data[i + 1] });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Работает, но почему то не работает в zabbix JavaScript предобработке, там используется JavaScript ducktape синтаксис, ругается на строку цикла (https://duktape.org/dukweb.html)

Comment: В цикле for исправил let на var, ошибка "SyntaxError:parse error (line 4)" ушла, но появилась другая  "SyntaxError: invalid object literal (line 5)", в строке "result.push({ ...json.data[i], ...json.data[i + 1] });"

Comment: @АртемЧернышев Вам стоит в вопросе уточнять, что движок JS, который используется, имеет ограничения. В данном случае он, наверное, не поддерживает spread syntax в литералах объектов. Попробуйте заменить `result.data.push({ ...json.data[i], ...json.data[i + 1] });` на `result.data.push(Object.assign({}, json.data[i], json.data[i + 1]));`